# How to run external script from iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ruby, system

I have jailbroken iPhone and ruby script in `/var/root/` directory and I need to execute commands from native iPhone app (coded in XCode). I tried to run `system("ruby /var/root/my_script.rb")` function from native app (imported Foundation.h), but the call didn't execute the script.

Thanks for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Played with Ruby on a jailbroken 4.2.1 3GS. The script contained the following code (it displays 0, 1 and 2 in 3 rows, one after each other):

*3.times {|x|p x}*

and was placed in the root. I invoked it from the app delegate of a very simple View-Based app, in *- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions*, as follows:

```
NSLog(@"1");
    system("ruby /rt.rb");
NSLog(@"1.4");
   NSLog(@"2 %@", system("ruby /rt.rb"));    
NSLog(@"3");
```

Xcode's console displayed the following, showing the Ruby script has been successfully run:

*Tue Nov 15 12:13:13 wr-3gs rubytest[501] : 1
Tue Nov 15 12:13:14 wr-3gs UIKitApplication:com.yourcompany.rubytest[0x687f][501] : 0
Tue Nov 15 12:13:14 wr-3gs UIKitApplication:com.yourcompany.rubytest[0x687f][501] : 1
Tue Nov 15 12:13:14 wr-3gs UIKitApplication:com.yourcompany.rubytest[0x687f][501] : 2
Tue Nov 15 12:13:14 wr-3gs rubytest[501] : 1.4
Tue Nov 15 12:13:14 wr-3gs UIKitApplication:com.yourcompany.rubytest[0x687f][501] : 0
Tue Nov 15 12:13:14 wr-3gs UIKitApplication:com.yourcompany.rubytest[0x687f][501] : 1
Tue Nov 15 12:13:14 wr-3gs UIKitApplication:com.yourcompany.rubytest[0x687f][501] : 2
Tue Nov 15 12:13:14 wr-3gs rubytest[501] : 2 (null)
Tue Nov 15 12:13:14 wr-3gs rubytest[501] : 3*

That is, it should work without

1. forcing the invocation of 'ruby' as a root user (as in *system("echo alpine | ruby '/rt.rb' root");*)
2. fully providing the path of the ruby executable.

Nevertheless, you could try doing the last two (running as root and/or providing the full ruby executable path) - they might work.